# barplot with 2 columns

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I would like to create barplot horizontal with the following dataframe

```
studentData = { 
0 : {
    'stylevel' : 'bachelor',
    'q' : 'agree',
    'Type' : 'Nascent'
    },
1 : {
    'stylevel' : 'bachelor',
    'q' : 'very',
    'Type' : 'Nascent'
    },
2 : {
    'stylevel' : 'master',
    'q' : 'very',
    'Type' : 'Active'
    },    
3 : {
    'stylevel' : 'master',
    'q' : 'agree',
    'Type' : 'Active'
    },  
4 : {
    'stylevel' : 'master',
    'q' : 'agree',
    'Type' : 'Student'
    },
}

dfObj = pd.DataFrame(studentData)
dfObj = dfObj.T
```

I'm using the following code to plot the graph

```
dfObj['q'].value_counts().plot(kind='barh')
```

Could you tell me how I could create the same graph using the Type column in the original dataframe to split the q data in 3 subgroups (i.e. Student, Active and nascent)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have three options.

using pandas:

```
dfObj.groupby('Type')['q'].value_counts().plot(kind='barh')
```

[image: pandas bar plot]

using pandas stacked bars:

```
dfObj.groupby('Type')['q'].value_counts().unstack(level=0).plot.barh(stacked=True)
```

[image: pandas stacked bars]

using [`seaborn.catplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html):

```
import seaborn as sns
df2 = dfObj.groupby('Type')['q'].value_counts().rename('count').reset_index()
sns.catplot(data=df2, x='q', hue='Type', y='count', kind='bar')
```

[image: seaborn catplot]